# How to get applications list from Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I looked for answear to this question, but can not got any good solution.
[How to get the list of installed application from google play store in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195379/how-to-get-the-list-of-installed-application-from-google-play-store-in-android)
How can i get all installed application list for current account?
I know i can parse https://play.google.com/apps and get this list, but may be there is more correct way?
Thanks.

Comment: I have not done this as of now. I hope this will help you to get some clear picture. Please go through this qoura discussion https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-get-Android-application-details-from-Google-Play-Store-by-package-name

Comment: Thank you Mubarak. But it not i want